# Disjunctive normal form from a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, disjunctive-normal-form

I've got the following question regarding Disjunctive Normal Form:
[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhOl.png)

I've got answers for both of the questions and just want to check if they are correct

For the first part, the answer that I got is:

$$\begin{align} α(P,Q,R) \iff &(P \wedge Q \wedge Q) \vee  (P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R) \vee (P \wedge \neg Q \wedge \neg R) \vee (¬ P \wedge Q \wedge R)\\ &\vee (¬ P \wedge Q \wedge ¬ R) \vee (¬ P \wedge ¬ Q \wedge R) \vee (¬ P \wedge ¬ Q \wedge ¬ R)\end{align}$$

For the second part, which is to write a more compact Boolean expression for the predicate α(P,Q,R) with the truth table in the image, I got:

$$α(P,Q,R) \iff ¬ (¬ P \wedge ¬ Q \wedge R) $$

I'm more sure about the first one over the second one, but i'd be grateful if anyone would be able to see if they get the same answers and see if i've gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Your first answer is right. Please enclose the exercise as a figure in your question (not just a link). ($\alpha$ is not needed in the answer?)

Comment: @user376343 yeah it's needed but I wasn't sure how to get the symbol, added it in now. How do I enclose the exercise as a figure?

Comment: Alright changed it, I can't put in images until I have 10 reputation

Comment: It's ok, I can read the table. Since your first answer is right, I think you're be able to fix your second answer (... the case when we get $0$ is not $(0,0,1)$)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to show (1,1,0) for false, so I put that the statement is logically equivalent to not(not P and not Q and R), which I assumed would convert to (P and Q and not R) due to the double negation.

Comment: The first negation does it. So $¬ ( P \wedge  Q \wedge ¬ R)$ corresponds to " Any case *except* $(1,1,0).$ "

Comment: Ahh okay, makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ... and now apply Mr. de Morgan $( ¬ P \vee  ¬ Q \vee R).$  This helps to realize  the mistake.

Comment: So is the answer ¬(P∧Q∧¬R) or (¬P∨¬Q∨R)?

Comment: Both. "a" more compact form.